# If I'm tracking the number of clicks per day of a button, how would I log the possible 0 amount of clicks if a user never opened the app?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

To simplify the question, I'm using the example of logging/keeping track/storing the data of the amount of clicks of a button per day, for seven days, then repeating.  How would I go about this if the user does not open the app for at least one day?

Let's say the first day, the user clicks the button 3 times, so variable day_0 = 3.  For the second day, the user doesn't go into the app to click the button.  But on the third day, the user enters the app and clicks the button 2 times.  In this case, my desired initialization would be variables day_0 = 3, day_1 = 0, and day_2 = 2.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: By default, all counts will be initialized with zero and if user taps then the corresponding day you will update the value but then the important question is how you are tracking the days? How you which day is which? If you can share the code then only I can help more.

Comment: The tracking of each day is another problem I have.  I believe I will be using Calendar.  I just wanted to know if it's possible to do this first.

Comment: You would store the date that you start tracking clicks. Then you can easily determine how many days since you started. When you get a button click update the counts accordingly based on the day relative to the start day

Comment: Add the date as part of the logging, for any date that is missing in your log the count is 0